# How to disassemble these instructions

Tags: riscv

I am writing a little disassembler using riscv-spec-v2.0 and have some questions about the following instructions and how to correctly disassemble them:

1.
FENCE instruction has "pred" and "succ" bit fields in imm

2.
AMO instructions have "aq" and "rl" bits in in funct7

3.
Float instructions have a "rm" bit field in funct3

All of these bit fields seem to lack mappings in the assembler.
E.g. page 50 just says "FENCE" but not what to do with the intermediate.
Or page 33 has an example of putting .aq or .rl at the end but not what to do if both are present.

4.
SCALL, SBREAK are the same as ECALL, EBREAK
but there is also ERET: so why not drop SCALL and SBREAK
and just use ECALL, EBREAK and ERET because other wise it
is hard to disassemble these opcodes.

Comment: Did you take a look at what the RISC-V gcc toolchain's objdump does for these scenarios? When in doubt, I'd match it's behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current RISC-V assembler is terse for common defaults:

1. "FENCE" with no arguments is treated as a full fence (all bits set)
2. OK to have both on same instruction
3. Rounding mode not shown if not specified
4. ECALL and EBREAK will be the new standard names (will be clarified in the revised user ISA manual)

Comment: Thanks, but how exactly are the arguments of "FENCE" coded in the assembler? Just as intermediate like "FENCE imm"?

Comment: Yes. It takes the form FENCE pred, succ where pred or succ represent the immediates and are encoded with the corresponding letters (R,W,I,O). The commentary at the base of page 32 of the user manual gives examples of assembly for these cases (i.e. FENCE R,RW).